# Event Queueing Limit for Google Cloud function when max instance limit is set above 0

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using Google cloud functions,
On this page [Controlling Scaling Behaviour](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances?hl=en,)

Its written `Events destined for event-driven functions will automatically be saved until capacity is available`

What exactly and precisely is this capacity?, is it expandable? , how is it determined.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit in the documentation, thus I think there is no limit. I'm pretty sure that the event are backed with PubSub under the hood, and the limit is "infinite".

If an event takes more 7 days to be processed, it's possible that it will be lost (max retention in PubSub). But, if it's the case, your max instance limit is really not well set.